# How do I get domPDF to display my codeigniter view correctly

Tags: codeigniter-2, dompdf

I feel there is a small step that I am missing that apparently everyone on the other related questions understands.

I have created a simple **CI 2** view, controller and model, shown below:

I have installed **dompdf** into the helpers folder like so:

```
applications/helpers/dompdf

applications/helpers/dompdf/dompdf_help.php
```

What I want to happen is when user clicks the submit button on the view page, send form data to the db, then get a pdf of that filled in form.

Between getting underdefined var errors or nothing at all, except for the data going to db, I can't see what I am missing.

Could some please guide me?  What am I not getting here?

**View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>test pdf</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php // Change the css classes to suit your needs    

$attributes = array('class' => '', 'id' => '');
echo form_open('quicksubmit', $attributes); ?>

<p>
        <label for="title">Title <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error('title'); ?>

        <?php // Change the values in this array to populate your dropdown as required ?>
        <?php $options = array(
                    ''  => 'Please Select',
                    'Mrs'    => 'Mrs',
                    'Miss'    => 'Miss',
                    'Ms'    => 'Ms',
                    'Mr'    => 'Mr',
                  ); ?>

        <br /><?php echo form_dropdown('title', $options, set_value('title'))?>
</p>                                             

<p>
        <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        <?php echo form_error('first_name'); ?>
        <br /><input id="first_name" type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="100" value="<?php echo set_value('first_name'); ?>"  />
</p>

<p>
        <label for="last_name">Last Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <?php echo form_error('last_name'); ?>
        <br /><input id="last_name" type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="100" value="<?php echo set_value('last_name'); ?>"  />
</p>

<p>
        <label for="branch">Branch</label>
        <?php echo form_error('branch'); ?>

        <?php // Change the values in this array to populate your dropdown as required ?>
        <?php $options = array(
                    ''  => 'Please Select',
                    'Branch 1'    => 'Branch One',
                    'Branch 2'    => 'Branch Two',
                  ); ?>

        <br /><?php echo form_dropdown('branch', $options, set_value('branch'))?>
</p>                                             

<p>
        <label for="zip">Zip</label>
        <?php echo form_error('zip'); ?>
        <br /><input id="zip" type="text" name="zip" maxlength="7" value="<?php echo set_value('zip'); ?>"  />
</p>


<p>
        <?php echo form_submit( 'submit', 'Submit'); ?>
</p>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

class Quicksubmit extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('quicksubmit_model');
    }   
    function index()
    {           
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required|trim|xss_clean|max_length[50]');          
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'trim|xss_clean|max_length[100]');            
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean|max_length[100]');         
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('branch', 'Branch', 'trim|xss_clean|max_length[100]');            
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('zip', 'Zip', 'trim|xss_clean|is_numeric|max_length[7]');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error">', '</span>');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) // validation hasn't been passed
        {
            $this->load->view('quicksubmit_view');
        }
        else // passed validation proceed to post success logic
        {
            // build array for the model
                    $this->pdf($output);

                        $form_data = array(
                                    'title' => set_value('title'),
                                    'first_name' => set_value('first_name'),
                                    'last_name' => set_value('last_name'),
                                    'branch' => set_value('branch'),
                                    'zip' => set_value('zip')
                                    );

            // run insert model to write data to db

            if ($this->quicksubmit_model->SaveForm($form_data) == TRUE) // the information has therefore been successfully saved in the db
            {
                redirect('quicksubmit/success');   // or whatever logic needs to occur
            }
            else
            {
            echo 'An error occurred saving your information. Please try again later';
            // Or whatever error handling is necessary
            }
        }
    }
    function success()
    {
            redirect(base_url(),'refresh');     
            /*echo 'this form has been successfully submitted with all validation being passed. All messages or logic here. Please note
            sessions have not been used and would need to be added in to suit your app';*/
    }
        function pdf()
            {
                 $this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));
                 // page info here, db calls, etc.     
                 $html = $this->load->view('quicksubmit_view', $data, true);
                 pdf_create($html, 'filename');
                 /*or
                 $data = pdf_create($html, '', false);
                 write_file('name', $data);*/
                 //if you want to write it to disk and/or send it as an attachment    
            }
}
?>
```

**Model**

```
<?php

class Quicksubmit_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------

      /** 
       * function SaveForm()
       *
       * insert form data
       * @param $form_data - array
       * @return Bool - TRUE or FALSE
       */

    function SaveForm($form_data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('quicksubmit', $form_data);

        if ($this->db->affected_rows() == '1')
        {
            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
}
?>
```

**dompdf_help.php file**

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

function pdf_create($html, $filename='', $stream=TRUE) 
{
    require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $dompdf->load_html($html);
        $dompdf->render();
        if ($stream) {
            $dompdf->stream($filename.".pdf");
        } else {
            return $dompdf->output();
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm not a user of CI, so forgive my ignorance. You call `$this->pdf($output)` but don't set $output and the `pdf` method doesn't accept any parameters. Just a code cleanliness point. In the `pdf` method you load a view, passing it the `$data` variable. Is that variable set by CI because it's not defined anywhere else that I can see? You might want to strip out everything you don't need to simplify the code and address the errors (which you should post here since they may be relevant).

Answer (score 1):

you were nearly there!

It is probably better to store dompdf in the third_party folder, and it is not a code igniter helper. - see the path i store it in in the constructor. Then it is always available.

Also, it is probably better to do the 'work' of the program in the model, so this includes making PDFs etc.

- don't use a ?> at the end of your code.

i modded your code to work, and verified it did work.  it simply saves a file named tmp/name.pdf.  I am sure you can work out the rest.  i did comment out the database loader because that wasn't needed for me to test the code.

see enc.

```
<?php

 class Quicksubmit extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    //$this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->model('quicksubmit_model');

    global $_dompdf_show_warnings;global $_dompdf_debug;global $_DOMPDF_DEBUG_TYPES;global $_dompdf_warnings;$_dompdf_show_warnings = FALSE;
    require_once(realpath(APPPATH."third_party/dompdf")."/dompdf_config.inc.php"); // remember that the constant DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR may need to be changed.
    spl_autoload_register('DOMPDF_autoload');
}   
function index()
{           
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required|trim|xss_clean|max_length[50]');          
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'trim|xss_clean|max_length[100]');            
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean|max_length[100]');         
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('branch', 'Branch', 'trim|xss_clean|max_length[100]');            
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('zip', 'Zip', 'trim|xss_clean|is_numeric|max_length[7]');

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<br /><span class="error">', '</span>');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) // validation hasn't been passed
    {
        $this->load->view('quicksubmit_view');
    }
    else // passed validation proceed to post success logic
    {
        // build array for the model


        $form_data = array(
                    'title' => set_value('title'),
                    'first_name' => set_value('first_name'),
                    'last_name' => set_value('last_name'),
                    'branch' => set_value('branch'),
                    'zip' => set_value('zip')
                    );
        $this->pdf($form_data);
        // run insert model to write data to db

        if ($this->quicksubmit_model->SaveForm($form_data) == TRUE) // the information has therefore been successfully saved in the db
        {
            redirect('quicksubmit/success');   // or whatever logic needs to occur
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'An error occurred saving your information. Please try again later';
        // Or whatever error handling is necessary
        }
    }
}
function success()
{
        redirect(base_url(),'refresh');     
        /*echo 'this form has been successfully submitted with all validation being passed. All messages or logic here. Please note
        sessions have not been used and would need to be added in to suit your app';*/
}
function pdf($data)
{
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $html = $this->load->view('quicksubmit_view', $data, true);
    $dompdf->set_paper('a4','portrait');
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $pdf = $dompdf->output();
    write_file('tmp/name.pdf', $pdf);

}
}
```